# Auto deployment of PHP applications

Tags: php, mysql

My team currently has a development web/database server and a live deployment web server and a live database server. We use SVN with the repository stored on the development server but the problem is our deployment process.

Currently when we need to deploy an update to the live application we simply use SFTP to transfer from the repository to the live web server and then amend the database on the live server to reflect the development database. This is a really slow process as we also minify all javascript and CSS files.

I have used Capistrano for Ruby and Cruise Control for java but I have never used anything for PHP. I'd rather not have to build our own if something already existed. Does anyone know of anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out my recent bounty question:

[**Setting up a deployment / build / CI cycle for PHP projects**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects)

I got a number of very good product recommendations. There's also a Cruise Control connector for PHP, [**phpUnderControl**](http://phpundercontrol.org/about.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did a great job with auto deployment using CruiseControl and phpUnderControl

http://topecoders.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-install-cruisecontrol.html

They work pretty cool with all tests and code analysis being done automatically. It also deploys projects on every successful build.