# Build Systems for PHP Web Apps

Tags: php, unix, build, automation, deployment

I want to start automating more of my web development process so I'm looking for a build system. I write mostly PHP apps on Mac OS X and deploy Linux servers over FTP. A lot of my clients have basic hosting providers so shell access to their servers is typically not available, however remote MySQL access is usually present. Here is what I want to do with a build system:

- When Building:

  - Lint JavaScript Files
  - Validate CSS Files
  - Validate HTML Files
  - Minify and concatenate JS and CSS files
  - Verify PHP Syntax
  - Set Debug/Production flags
- When Deploying

  - Checkout latest version from SVN
  - Run build process
  - Upload files to server via FTP
  - Run SQL scripts on remote DB

I realize this is a lot of work to automate but I think it would be worth it. So what is the best way to start down this path? Is there a system that can handle builds and deploys, or should I search for separate solutions? What systems would you recommend?

Comment: You may also be interested in my recent bounty question: [Setting up a deployment / build / CI cycle for PHP projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you ask for can be done with [Phing](http://phing.info/)

Phing is a deployment framework written in PHP and modeled after Apache Ant. It comes with a large set of ready-to-use deployment tasks, including database deployment, remote file transfers and VCS connectivity. If you are missing functionality, you can extend Phing with standard PHP.

Phing provides the following features:

- Simple XML buildfiles
- Rich set of provided tasks
- Easily extendable via PHP classes
- Platform-independent: works on UNIX, Windows, MacOSX
- No required external dependencies
- Built & optimized for ZendEngine2/PHP5

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to have a look to [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), an extensible continuous integration server.
The supported features are available [here](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson).

Among the other languages, it supported PHP. [This article](http://toptopic.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/php-and-hudson/) presents some nice plugins for PHP. The article is also suggesting [Phing](http://phing.info/trac/) for the build. See Gordon's answer for details.