# Website deployment techniques

Tags: deployment, build, web, automation

I'm working on improving a small intranet where files are currently edited directly on the server (connected via Samba). As you can imagine, I'd like to vastly improve this workflow with things like:

- Version control
- Validation of JavaScript and CSS (or SAAS) files
- Minification of JavaScript and CSS (or SAAS) files
- Transfer to live server (ideally to the server mounted, rather than SSH etc.)

Naturally I'd like this to be as automated as possible.

I've been looking around for a few hours on this subject and have come across similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561666/build-systems-for-php-web-apps?rq=1) and read about various tools (Ant, Capistrano, Maven, Phing, others…), but I'm struggling to get an overview of the whole process. Are there any good books or tutorials that step through a workflow, perhaps pointing out suitable tools along the way and showing basic examples?

Comment: My advice would be to start with just Phing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bunch of guides on our site about deployments. Take a look, maybe you will find the useful. Here's one about deployments best practices:

http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/best-practices.html

Here's one about configuring your first Capistrano recipe:

http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html

And this one is about managing Capistrano deployment with Beanstalk:

http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/managing-capistrano-deployments.html

Good luck!