# unit, integration and system tests for PHP applications

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

We were given an assignment to develop a prototype for a customer community. It was suggested PHP as the programming language. (but we're not supposed to actually code it, just a prototype with documentation is required)

I'm wondering what are the best practices/ tools used in Unit testing, Integration Testing and System testing for such a php app

Thanks

Comment: Prototype or mock up?  A prototype usually is coded, but quickly and might not be tested at all.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP, the big name in Unit Testing is arguably [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de). Related questions:

- [Best way to implement unit testing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842/best-way-to-implement-unit-testing-in-php)
- [What’s the state of PHP unit testing frameworks in 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408860/whats-the-state-of-php-unit-testing-frameworks-in-2010)

As for the integration aspect, maybe this question will give you some pointers:

- [Setting up a deployment / build / CI cycle for PHP projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects)