# php development workflow

Tags: php, svn, apache, hudson

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up a deployment / build / CI cycle for PHP projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects)

I'm looking to setup a development pipeline that will allow me to separate my code into three categories: live, staging and dev
I'm using a2hosting's shared hosting package with ssh access. Ideally I'd like to have three paths on the server for each one of those branches. I'd like to keep each version of the site into svn so I can quickly revert the entire branch if something goes wrong. I'm assuming this is done with svn tags, not sure. I also plan on using symfony as a php framework.

I'd also like to setup something like hudson for continuous integration and testing before transferring the site from dev to staging.

basically, I'm pretty confused with the whole iteration, build and testing process and how to do it cleanly and effectively

I was wondering if anyone had workflow recommendations or if you agree with my method, any links on setting up each aspect of the pipeline.

Thanks in advance