# What are the best practices for a php from Deployment Winxp to Winxp?

Tags: php, apache, git, deployment, windows-xp

Where i begin to work, they are using a Remote Desktop Conection, to transfer files and manage the server, but that seems to me really insecure and a good way to cause errors and take down the apache/php/mysql stack.

I was proposing FTP to transfer files more easyly (and secure compared to the other way) but started reading about php deployment. It seems pretty easy on Linux, but on windows i havent found out wich is the best way to do it..

So far i think git on the server, and comit to it from the developer is my best shot, but what about database deployment?

Phing/jenkins/capistrano seem overly complex.. but will try if you guys think is good

Comment: Many Linux deployment tools are also available on Windows. You might want to check that out. Also possibly interesting: [Setting up a deployment / build / CI cycle for PHP projects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2180460)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I am using is database migration scripts. They look like this

```
db-update-001.sql
db-update-002.sql
```

I have a script which sequentially executes them and creates *.ok file for each if it's successful. *.sql files contain "alter" statements and are stored in Git. The .ok files are not stored, so if you distribute changes, you need to imprint only those without .ok files.

I use this file: https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/tools/update.sh

but since you are in MS environment, you might need to do something different.

Answer (score 0):

While MSRDP is not the most secure protocol around, its a very long way aead of FTP.

FTP is intrinsically insecure - it sends passwords as clear text. It's also a PITA to manage across a stateful firewall even where you can ensure consistent PASV behaviour.

However you do need a method for transfering files which can be scripted / automated.

I'd go back and have a long hard look at the available deployment tools - I can't comment on how well the other products compare with phing, only having used the latter - however mostly I've used stuff developed in house.

Since you really should be using a version control system - I'd recommend considering using it as your file delivery mechanism too.