# How do I plan my git workflow around some folders containing dynamic content

Tags: git, github, wamp

I am working on a PHP website with a friend and we want to convert to using proper version control, but because the site contains a lot of constantly changing files, e.g. user uploaded images, we are unsure on how to set it up.

I tried looking on Google for a solution to my situation but I'm not even sure what to search for :P

My question is this, how do we develop the site on our local machines running Apache and GIT if there are folders that contain images and other constantly changing content that users have uploaded. Because the content would always be changing, and also over time would probably become quite large, I thought we might just be able to use the git exclude feature but then the links on the site pointing to this content would then be broken. Because the site is completely based around the content the users upload having those broken links makes it pretty much useless for testing.

Do you guys have any suggestions on how we would achieve a good GIT workflow without having to push a new version every time a user submits content to the site?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask yourselves what your reasons for wanting version control are.

Version control is used for keeping track of source code, so that you can work with that source code collaboratively and understand historically what changes have been made (for instance for bug analysis).

So you should **version control** the *source code* of the web site.

Both the images and the links you are talking about are part of the *content* of the web site. The content needs to be **backed up** regularly, so that you can recover from a bad situation (e.g. hardware failure).

It sounds to me like you may have mixed source code and content, at least conceptually. You should clarify that distinction and treat each part accordingly.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you! Do you think it would be sensible to make some scripts that would update out local copies of the content directory with the latest files from the server? I imagine we would use this every now and then when we want a fresh set of content. How do you think other projects would go about updating their local copy of the content folder? If I made a script I could also make it pull down the latest mysql structure too.

Comment: I think @NevilleK has a pretty good general answer to those questions. You may want to set up at least three different environments: development, test and production.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common situation - and there are a couple of things you probably want to consider.

Firstly, as Klas Melbourn writes, you probably don't want to add content or data from the live system to your source code control - that's what back-ups are for.

The second thing to consider is to introduce the concept of "environment" to your thinking - in most cases, you have at least 3 environments: Development - your machine, your friend's machine. The development environment should be predictable - so you probably want to have a bunch of representative user contributions in there, so you can test your code - but it should not (usually) have a complete copy of the live site content/data, because that slows your development process without adding much value. On Dev environments, you want to have lots of debugging information, including "rich" error messages.

The next environment is usually Test - you and your friend put your work together, and test it on a dedicated environment. Again, you want the content and data to be representative, but probably not include all the data from live. You do, however, want to have examples of edge cases - massive image, tiny image, image in weird aspect ratios etc. - so you can quickly test that everything works as you expect.

The final environment is "production" or "live" - here you obviously don't want the test data floating around, and you want to disable "rich" error messages, debug information, test accounts etc.

Managing all this can be a bit of a pain, and the most recent thinking is "[Continuous Delivery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery)"; check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects) for a way to do this with PHP.

Comment: This is very good information, thank you so much, I wasn't thinking of the content separate but it really should be, I just drew a diagram of the workflow and it makes much more sense now, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add path (your private config or log or generated content) in ".gitignore" (put in your repo or your home directory).

Comment: In the question I explained I cant use this as it will break all of the links that the site uses, sorry.