# Drupal 7 Continuous Integration Tools List

Tags: drupal-7, continuous-integration

Decided to have the continuous integration for Drupal 7.x project. wanted the list and their advantages to pick the suitable one.

Comment: has any one found any list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After waiting for answers for few days, i found best SO answer. In addition to that i'm adding [`Jenkins`](http://jenkins-ci.org/) too, it really helping a lot

Answer is:
[Setting up a deployment / build / CI cycle for PHP projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects/2225613#2225613)