# Continuous deployment without cloning whole repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server, continuous-deployment

I am searching for a solution to do continuous deployment in a cloud environment, more specific, in an Amazon AWS environment.

The code to be deployed are mainly Microsoft's ASP and PHP, so this framework should work on both platforms. As I have an auto-scale environment, this framework will work if it pulls the new code, like Puppet does.

My first thought was to deploy direct from the VCS, but I ended in a problem where all repository information was mirrored to the servers, as GIT, for instance, works. This is a problem because the repository keeps growing and the servers will demand more and more space.

I found Ansible, that works the way I need, but does not work on Windows environment. It only sends to the servers the production code, not the VCS repository, and keeps track which servers are updated.

Without using an easy-to-setup framework like this, I will need to create a Puppet + Jenkins + a VCS framework, where Jenkins creates the package from a VCS source code and Puppet delivers it.

Does anybody know any small framework for my needs or the Puppet + Jenkins + VCS is the way to go?

Comment: Did you try Elastic Beanstalk? Whenever you push to your GIT, aws.push pushes only latest changes and keeps only the code on your servers and not repository (example .git directory) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html I used Jenkins and now Bamboo to poll for a specific branch changes and automate this push to Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: @RakeshBollampally We already use Elastic Beanstalk in some systems, and it's true, the continuous deployment works flawlessly in it. But, I have some more complex environments that we decided to no use Beanstalk, so is for these environments that I'm searching for a continuous deployment framework.

Comment: [git clone --bare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959924/whats-the-difference-between-git-clone-mirror-and-git-clone-bare) will do some of what you want. You'll also find this is a [commonly solved problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects), so there's no reason to invent something from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Consider CloudMunch (www.cloudmunch.com) for this. The platform is built exactly to solve this kind of polyglot requirements.

*Disclaimer: I work for CloudMunch*